# Не грузится Manjaro с флешки

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro

Установил Manjaro на флешку, выбрал при загрузке и начал грузиться с неё. Не грузит, ошибка прикреплена на фото. 
Такая же ситуация возникала ранее с Ubuntu, но вылечил вписыванием вместо UUID при загрузке путь к устройству (/dev/sda), с Manjaro почему то не получается. 
Я не очень опытный в этом вопросе, поэтому хотелось бы получить ответ как для новичка, подробно рассписанный.
Буду очень благодарен. 
[image: error]

Во время загрузки не видит dev/sdb вообще, только внутренние диски с виндой... 
[image]

Comment: я думаю, что новичку будет проще переустановить систему.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin перестановка системы не помогает

Comment: значит, вы неправильно устанавливаете. для справки: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/hibernate-device-not-found-after-unplugging-2nd-hdd/1788

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я определённо правильно установил. Как и убунту прошлый раз, но после установки UUID по какой-то причине меняется, в убунту я исправил, с Manjaro не получается

Comment: вы можете: загрузиться с флэшки, подмонтировать файловую систему и показать файл /etc/fstab?

Comment: @DmitryErohin я все могу, если расскажите как :)

Comment: 1. грузитесь с флэшки; 2. Монтируйте файловую систему (sudo mkdir /mnt/arch && sudo mount /dev/sd[XX] /mnt/arch, где sd[XX] - раздел с корневой файловой системы) 3. Приложите результат `cat /mnt/arch/etc/fstab`

Comment: @DmitryErohin
    `# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
    #
    # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device; this may
    # be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices that works even if
    # disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
    #
    # <file system>                           <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
    UUID=5ac2311e-017a-4375-ac46-182e1259eb70 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0       1
    UUID=ea9fee35-433f-4211-a1ce-a732c0ce860f swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0       0`

Comment: `/dev/sda4            /          ext4       rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 1
/dev/sda2            /boot      ext4       rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 2`

Так у меня, убрал комментарии. Корень /dev/sda4, отдельный раздел под бут /dev/sda2

Comment: @DmitryErohin это куда?

Comment: это /etc/fstab из моего арчика.